# How to it make pure?

Tags: scala, akka-stream, scala-cats

I have following `scala` code:

```
import akka.Done
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.kafka.ConsumerMessage.CommittableOffsetBatch
import akka.kafka.scaladsl.Consumer
import akka.kafka.{ConsumerSettings, Subscriptions}
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.{ConsumerConfig, ConsumerRecord}
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

import scala.concurrent.Future

object TestConsumer {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    implicit val system = ActorSystem("KafkaConsumer")
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

    val consumerSettings = ConsumerSettings(system, new StringDeserializer, new StringDeserializer)
      .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
      .withGroupId("group1")
      .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")


    val result = Consumer
      .committableSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics("test"))
      .mapAsync(2)(rec => Future.successful(rec.record.value()))
      .runWith(Sink.foreach(ele => {
        print(ele)
        system.terminate()
      }))
  }
}
```

As you can recognize, the application consumes message from `kafka` printed out on the shell.

`runWith` is not pure, it generates some side effect, print out the received message and shutdown the actor.

The question is, how to make it pure with [cats IO effects](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect)? It is possible?

Comment: Doing `system.terminate()` foreach stream element is a quite bad idea

Comment: How to make it better?

Comment: Closing the system on each element of the stream, system that's used to create the materializer running the streaming, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need cats `IO` to make it pure. Note that your `sink` is already pure, because it's just the value that describes what will happen when it's used (in this case *using* means "connecting to the `Source` and running the stream").

```
    val sink: Sink[String, Future[Done]] = Sink.foreach(ele => {
      print(ele)
      // system.terminate() // PROBLEM: terminating the system before stream completes!
    })
```

The problem you described has nothing to do with purity. The problem is that the `sink` above closes over the value of `system`, and then tries to `terminate` it when processing each element of the source.

Terminating the `system` means that you are destroying the whole runtime environment (used by `ActorMaterializer`) that is used to run the stream. This should only be done when your stream completes.

```
val result: Future[Done] = Consumer
  .committableSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics("test"))
  .mapAsync(2)(rec => Future.successful(rec.record.value()))
  .runWith(sink)

result.onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
```